# Base class of all controls that has DataSource, DisplayMember and ValueMember properties

Tags: c#, datasource, valuemember

I am programming in `C#` `WinForms`. I want to know, how can I find any controls that has `DataSource` property, also `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` properties?

What is that controls base class? is it `Control` class or what?
I want to have a method to return a "Control" base object, that has all 3 `DataSource`, `DisplayMember` and `ValueMamber` properties.

So I'll can assign a `ComboBox` or `ListBox` to that return object. For example:

```
public myReturnType GetControl()
{
    //Some Code Here
     ...

    return myReturnType;
}

ComboBox a = GetControl();
ListBox  b = GetControl();
...
```

After that assignment, both `a` and `b` controls, has desire `DataSourse`, `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually they are derived from base class [ListControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx) which has all three properties defined in Base. So you can check if a control is of type [ListControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx) it will have all three properties.

If you want to investigate such information simply press `F12` or use `Right click` and `GoToDefinition` for any class and look for base classes and other information for builtin types.